# Euler's proof of infinite primes first since Euclid?

Tags: number-theory, euler, euclid, primes

**Q.** Is it true that Euler's proof of infinite primes was the first since Euclid's which was from around 300BC?

---

**Note:** By Euler's proof, I mean the use of his Euler product formula for the zeta function $\zeta(s)$ which diverges as $s\rightarrow\infty$, implying an infinitude of factors in the product, which means an infinite of primes.

Comment: what you meant in your question is that the zeta function $\zeta (s)$ diverges when $s=1$ (in other words, the harmonic series diverges as $n$ tends to $\infty$) and not when $s$ tends to infinity (it actually converges for $s>1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proof by Goldbach, which appears in a letter he wrote to Euler in 1730 (a few years before Euler published his product formula for the zeta function). It is as follows: if $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ (that is, if $F_n$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> Fermat number), then$$F_n=F_1F_2\ldots F_{n-1}+2.\tag1$$Since each $F_n$ is odd, it follows from $(1)$ that, if $n\ne m$, then $F_n$ and $F_m$ are relatively prime. So, take a prime factor $p_n$ of $F_n$, and the set $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots\}$ will be an infinite set of prime numbers.

Comment: Thanks @josé-carlos-santos - that is very helpful. Do you have a reference for when Euler published his product formula and in which book? I'm keen to reproduce the original texts as part of teaching.

Comment: also thanks to Jose's comment I found this https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/infinite/goldbach.html

Comment: You will find the complete reference [here](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/backup/E072.html).

Comment: A thread on MO regarding Goldbach's proof of the infinitude of primes: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22316/fermat-numbers-and-the-infinitude-of-primes